# OS on a extended partition

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning

I have a laptop with Windows-7 installed on it. The disk currently has 4 partitions, all of type NTFS. I am sure one of them would be an extended partition as only 3 primary partitions are allowed. I can check that using diskpart on Windows-7 cmd prompt.

Now I want to install Ubunut 10.04 on that extended partition to have a dual boot system.

1. How can I create a extended partition of my chosen size (50GB) in the current set of partitions?
2. Can I use this 50 GB that I want to create, for installing Ubuntu. Would it boot from this extended partition?
3. Does that extended partition to install ubuntu need to be formatted to ext2 or something. If yes Can diskpart do that?

Comment: Duplicate.  This is the same questioner, with the same question, as at ["Formatting a partition to ext2 partition."](http://superuser.com/questions/286010/formatting-a-partition-to-ext2-partition).

Answer (score 2):

> I am sure one of them would be an extended partition as only 3 primary partitions are allowed.

Nope, you can have 4 primary partitions on a HDD. This does **not** leave room for other partitions on that HDD.

> How can I create a extended partition of my chosen size (50GB) in the current set of partitions?

You cannot. You must convert one primary into an extended one first. Be sure that you have a backup before trying.

> Can I use this 50 GB that I want to create, for installing Ubuntu. Would it boot from this extended partition?

Yes, you can install and boot Ubuntu from an extended partition. You might need to install the bootloader (grub) into the MBR.

> Does that extended partition to install ubuntu need to be formatted to ext2 or something. If yes Can diskpart do that?

Don't try to mess with Linux partitions from Windows. Just leave the 50GB unformatted.

Comment: Current problem I am facing is the 50GB partition which I allocated in Windows, does not get recognized during Ubuntu install/setup. I tried leaving it as unallocated space/no filesystem written to it.Also tried formatting it to NTFS. Still Ubuntu setup couldnt recognize it, where I could ask it to install. What could be the reason? Then what are my options/steps?